# The definition of slice (orbifolds)

Tags: group-actions, orbifolds

The following definition is from the paper "Non-abelian convexity by symplectic cuts", except that I substitute the words orbifold by manifold and suborbifold with submanifold,  since I'm not familiar with notion of orbifolds.

> Definition: Suppose that a group G acts on a manifold M. Given a point $m \in M$ with isotropy group $G_m$, a submanifold $U \subset M $ containing $m$ is a slice at $m$ if $U$ is $G_m$-invariant, $G.U$ is a neighborhood of $m$, and the map
> $$G ×_{G_m}U \rightarrow G.U, [a,u] \rightarrow a.u $$
> is an isomorphism. In other words, $G.y \cap U = G_m.y$ and $G_y \subset G_m$ for all $y \in U$.

I don't understand the last sentence in this definition, namely why does the definition of slice as given by authors is equivalent to the fact that $G.y \cap U = G_m.y$ and $G_y \subset G_m$ for all $y \in U$ ?

Comment: The fact $G_y\subseteq G_m$ is obvious from definition of orbifold.  The $G\cdot y\cap U=G_m\cdot y$ comes from restricting the isomorphism to $G_m\times_{G_m}U\to G_m\cdot U=U$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! But I still don't understand the first answer! I don't see why the definition of orbifold (like in this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2285573/confusion-about-definition-of-orbifold?r=SearchResults) imlplies that $G.y \subset G.m$ for all $y \in U$, Could you elaborate further please?